# How to identify an iOS hotspot from the command line?

Tags: macos, wifi, airport, command-line, tethering

Is it possible from the command line to identify whether the current Wi-Fi connection, or a detected SSID, is an iOS personal/instant hotspot?

I know OS X can detect this, as it shows a specific "hotspot" icon in the topbar when scanning the list of SSIDs or when being connected to an iPhone (see screenshot)

I tried using `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I` and `ifconfig` but I'm not able to find information that helps me identify an iOS hotspot.
[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: This does NOT have an answer there.  OP here specifically asked for a command line method.